# Loop Through Non Blank Cells

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Column A and B Data]

I just want to know how to loop through the non blank cells on Column A. What I'm trying to do is copy the contents on [A1:B1] to be added on top of each non blank cells on Column A. So far I have counted the non blank cells on column A but I'm stuck. I know that an Offset function should be used for this.

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim NonBlank as Long

NonBlank = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheet(1).[A:A])

    For i = 1 to NonBlank
        [A1:B1].Copy Offset(1,0). "I'm stuck here"  
    Next i
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are those merged cells? or is the background just colored white?

Comment: @BruceWayne - there's just colored white. I haven't got any errors cause I don't know what to code. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example to simulate the effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> from Cell A1 and display the Address, Value in the Immediate Window:

```
Sub HopToNextNonBlankCellBelow()
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oRng = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print "Cell Address", "Cell Value"
    Do
        Set oRng = oRng.End(xlDown)
        If Not IsEmpty(oRng) Then Debug.Print oRng.Address(0, 0), oRng.Value
    Loop Until oRng.Row = Rows.Count
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to fill the headers for each Product, try this...

```
Sub FillHeaders()
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:B1").Copy

For Each Rng In Range("A3:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Areas
    If Rng.Cells(1).Value <> Range("A1").Value Then
        Rng.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next Rng
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I've (probably) overcounted the rows at 1000, but it likely won't make a difference with your performance. If you wanted to be more precise, there are hundreds of articles on how to find the last row of a range. As for the **Offset** function, it references a cell in relation to the one we're looping through. In the example below, the code is saying `cell.offset(0,1)` which means one cell to the right of the cell we are currently looping through. A clearer (less loopy!) example would be if you typed: `Range("A10").offset(0,1)` it would be the same as typing `Range("B10")`

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("A2:A1000").Cells
If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
End If
Next Cell
```